# hostname wont work on SSH in public network

Tags: windows, networking, ssh, automation, openssh

my SSH client wont push request with my computer name(host name), it works only with my ipv4(IP Address) of my laptop when connected to campus network(public network), how can i fix this?(my automation depends on this)
My server is windows laptop
and my client iOS iPhone

Comment: You would need to either make your hostname available on the actual internet (e.g. using a DynDNS service might be an option) or tweak name resolution on your client (e.g. by using the hosts file).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add the computer name to the local host file: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

That should make it resolve the computername for you.

More info here:
https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/

Comment: and what address is my laptop?

Comment: Just write Hostname in a command prompt then you will get your hostname.

Comment: To get the IP of your computer you just type ipconfig in a command prompt. Then you have both values you need for your hosts file.

Comment: but the ipv4 keeps changing on every network!

Comment: i want to have static host name for my computer, when trying to control it via my iphone

Comment: How can i access my pc via hostname on every network i connect(both devices are connected to the same network)

Comment: In that case you should either move your application to some kind of cloud service, or you should check out DynDns.